# sphinx search how to ignore html encode text

Tags: sphinx

I'm having this problem when i search for item 123 in title i would not get back the correct data.

In sphinx i have a field called title some models have trade mark in html.

i can't remove html encode from title.

any way i can ignore those words?

for example search for `123&trade`;

would like to ignore ™

```
MATCH('@!(content,synonym) 123')
```

I have tried using stopwords, exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I would use `regex_filter` to search and replace these possibly to nothing.

Its about the only directive that applies befor charset_table tokenization